# Mongo DB Site to Site Migration

Tags: backup, mongodb, restore, migration

I am somewhat new to MongoDB but I do have some experience with MySQL and PostgreSQL. Currently, I need to migrate Mongo DB from one site to another. The sites should be identical (development and production) but the production ran a bit forward in terms of content so we want to make sure they are mirroring each other. How do I do it? The mongo is run on the CentOS Linux system. Will this be as easy as doing a dump and restore? Or is there more involved?

Comment: Are we talking of the data? Quite some legislations prohibit  the use your customers data for other things than processing their orders / service requests / etc. If this isn't a concern, use mongodump on a secondary, since this prevents almost any impact on your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think just -- exporting db and taking out the json file and import in another system.

Or You can directly copy the db from one location to another----
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/